# MySQL: Undefined indexes, even though they have been defined

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have some pretty simple code:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT  max(id) as id, ip, max(entry), COUNT(ip) AS count 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY max(id) asc
");

$i = 0;

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num_rows;


while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $entry = $row['entry'];
    $ip = $row['ip'];
    $count = $row['count'];
    $i++;
?>



<tr width="100%" align="center">
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entry; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td>
    <form style="display:inline;" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ip; ?>" name="ip" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Ban IP" name="submit" />
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id
Notice: Undefined index: entry
Notice: Undefined index: ip
Notice: Undefined index: count
```

But as far as I can see, I have defined the indexes in the SQL statement, any help would be appreciated. It selects the data using the column names id, ip, entry and creates the index "count" for the count of ip's, so why does it say that it hasn't been defined?

Comment: I'm sorry if the description seems sparse, I just don't know how else to describe it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the result row as an associative array you should use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Also you  *haven't* defined `entry`despite your claim that you have. Change this:

```
SELECT max(id) as id, ip, max(entry), COUNT(ip) AS count
```

To this:

```
SELECT max(id) as id, ip, max(entry) AS entry, COUNT(ip) AS count
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysql_fetch_row()`, which returns the data as an indexed array. You want `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) returns an enumerated array.

You want [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Alternatively you could fetch values by column index:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $id = $row[0];
    $ip = $row[1];
    $entry = $row[2];
    $count = $row[3];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try mysql_fetch_assoc instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need `mysql_fetch_assoc`, `mysql_fetch_row` returns a plain array with numerical indexes.